# I Accidentally Deleted some GUI files! [UBUNTU 20.04]

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, gui

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4. I accidentally deleted some files (not many) which had `cairo` in their names, which may be related to the GUI.

After that, when I restarted my PC, there were some errors and the system does not seem to boot up; it's stuck at a blank window. I can log in with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and browse my disk, though:

[image: all the files are there]

[image: when i tried sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop]

I tried many things such as:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install gnome
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But this fails with an error saying:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this problem and restore those missing files?

Comment: by pressing "ctrl+alt+f5", i can login into my terminal.

Comment: Hello. A good start to any question is what version of Ubuntu, there is no 20.4 A lot more detail about the commands you have tried might help. Of course the best and maybe faster fix is to back up the data and re install.

Comment: the second command has an erro - should be `sudo apt install gnome`:

Comment: Can you post the whole error message? Maybe it is a simple mistype.

Comment: Did you do the damage using a terminal, or a GUI? If the terminal, please use the `history` command to show exactly what you did to break it, and add that information to your question. Do not post screenshots, edit in the text.

Answer (score 2):

Try to reinstall with

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop gnome
```

If you are sure you deleted cairo packages try this:

```
dpkg --get-selections | cut -f 1 | grep cairo > cairo-pkg-list.txt
```

and reinstall with

```
xargs -a cairo-pkg-list.txt sudo apt-get install
```

### Recommendation

Since you don't know what you deleted you can reinstall all packages using these commands:

```
dpkg --get-selections | cut -f 1  > pkg-list.txt
xargs -a pkg-list.txt sudo apt install
```

Comment: It again shows: sub process usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Is this the whole error message ?

Comment: i have added the photo.

Comment: try `sudo apt install --reinstall cairo-dock`

Comment: nothing worked men. again and again that dpkg issue. i guess i need to reinstall ubuntu from usb.

Comment: It's hard to say what to do with so less information! Is apt or working for other packages, did you try to install the missing packages show on your screen? Did you try to start your desktop (gnome, kde , ?? ) from cli ?

Comment: Did you made an update `sudo apt update` , because the file lists are missing "!